# Поиск по текстовому файлу C#

Tags: c#, .net

Всем добрый день. Такая проблема, нужно найти в текстовом файле определенное слово, например "имя" и записать в переменную следующее, после найденного, слово.
Например: *Имя Петя- нашло имя, в переменную записало Петя*. Понятно, что ориентироваться в отделении слов нужно по пробелам, но как это реализовать не знаю. В программировании новичок.

Comment: И что вы уже пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за ответы, взял ото всюду понемногу:

```
private void SearchInTxt(string fileLocation, string keyWord)
{
    string str = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);

    var kek = str.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '.', ',', ':', '\t' }).ToList();

    foreach (string s in kek)
    {
        if (s.Trim() != "" && Regex.IsMatch(s, keyWord))
        {
            textBox1.Text = kek[kek.IndexOf(keyWord) + 1] + " " + kek[kek.IndexOf(keyWord) + 3];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Считайте данные с тестового файла.
2. Разбейте полученное на части с помощью функции `Split`, используя
   пробел в качестве разделителя.
3. Найдите в полученном массиве нужное значение и получите его индекс.
4. Из массива возьмите значение с индексом на 1 или 2 больше от
   полученного на предыдущем шаге.
5. Используйте его.

Answer (score 1):

При использовании такого кода - будет выбрано следующее слово, но тогда остается проблема с выбором фамилии, например)

```
var inputStr = "some text name Petya Petyochkin some text some text";
var nameValue = "name";
var inputStrAList = inputStr.Split(' ').ToList();
string result = inputStrAList[(inputStrAList.IndexOf(nameValue) + 1)]; //result = "Petya"
```

Comment: Но ведь данная конструкция заменит все вхождения слова "имя" на "Петя". Мне показалось автору вопроса надо несколько иное.

Comment: @AleksandrZharinov спасибо. Осознал ошибку и исправил. У автора не совсем точное описание проблемы, надо бы отредактировать

Comment: @Yurii Manziuk Спасибо за ответ. Но разве проблема с поиском фамилии не решается конкатенацией с inputStrAList[(inputStrAList.IndexOf(nameValue) + 3)];?

Comment: @НикитаБлизнюк тут неоднозначная ситуация и вступают в силу ЕСЛИ: нет фамилии, а во "+3" индексе какое-то слово. И в этот самый момент вы используете то что нашли (имя и фамилию) в другом месте. Не красиво будет, когда всплывет имя "Петя блаблабла"
ЕСЛИ: фамилия указана, но вы ее просто не читаете (не используете "+3" индекс).  Не красиво будет, когда всплывет имя "Петя", хотя указано "Петя Петечкин"

тут нужно смотреть в сторону правильного формата входного текста с файла

Comment: @Yurii Manziuk входные файлы имеют довольно строгую структуру, поэтому не думаю, что это будет проблемой. Тем не менее еще раз благодарю за замечания.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
// Чтение из файла
string dataFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("<путь к файлу>");

// Парсинг строки в массив с указанным разделителем
string[] words = dataFromFile.Split(' ');
```

Далее ищете в массиве нужный элемент и берете следующий.